# Book about two worlds that collide; one world uses Sun-powered crystals as an energy source, while the other uses blood sacrifice

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m trying to find a book my father was looking for; he says it was one he read back in the early '90s.

He can’t exactly remember any solid details, but he did say that it involves a world that collides with another. One world uses crystal energy to power everything (the crystals are powered by the Sun), and the other world powers things using blood sacrifice.

He also thinks the cover may have been blue.

A bit of a long shot of course, but if anyone can help, I’d greatly appreciate it!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Rogue_planets_in_fiction it is not a big list so it is likely missing your story.  This one seems weird for example (pyramids = crystals Possibly? ) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfbane_(novel)

Comment: Can you ask your father if "worlds colliding" literally means two planets colliding? That doesn't seem likely as the collision would destroy both planets killing all life in the process. I wonder if he meant something like two different dimensions overlapping, or even just two empires encountering each other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It might just be [Echoes of the Great Song](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/568094) by David Gemmell, but it would need a rather loose interpretation of *worlds colliding*, and also the date is slightly out as it was published in 2002. If your father would like to check there is [a summary on the Fandom web site here](https://davidgemmell.fandom.com/wiki/Echoes_of_the_Great_Song).

The book starts on the world of the *Avatars* where crystals are used for power, but by the time the book starts these crystals are ceasing to work.

In the book the *Crystal Queen* teleports her continent from another world onto the world of the Avatars, which could I guess be *worlds colliding*. I can't remember if the Crystal Queen's world was another planet moving through space or some form of alternate dimension. Also I'm not sure if it's ever made clear exactly how this *teleporting* was done.

The people of the Crystal Queen, the *Almecs* (a thinly disguised version of the [Olmecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olmecs)), also use crystals for power but their crystals are charged by sacrificing humns and allowing their blood to soak into the crystals.

The book was published with lots of different covers. [There is a list of all the covers here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?23344). One of the covers is mainly blue:

[image: Echoes of the Great Song]

Comment: Just spoke to him on the phone, this is the one! I brushed past it in my collection because my version isn’t blue! You’ve done him a great service, thank you very much for your time sir, and have a great day!

Comment: @OpNamara wow, a lucky guess! :-)